# Member operators and doxygen difficulty

Tags: c++, doxygen

For one of my projects, I am required to do document all functions with doxygen, to reinforce good code practice. In my project, one ostream operator is giving me grief when we run it through our online grader. I have tried using doxygen autogenerators, and still am not able to escape this error.

> Member operator<<(ostream &out, const Item &item) (function) of file
> classes.cpp is not documented.

This is how my doxygen block is setup in the header:

```
/**
  * @brief asdf
  * asdfjkl;
  * @param out ...
  * @param order .....
  * @return ostream& out on completion
  */

ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const Item & item);
```

Am I doing this wrong? We didn't necessarily review the differences in documenting operators like this -- I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Which version of dxygen? What is in your doxygen configuration file (different from the default settings)? With a default settings file, the given example (after correcting `order` to `item`)  and doxygen 1.8.20  I have no warnings. One thing that is a bit strange here is that the error speaks of `cl;asses.cpp` and we have here a typical construct / prototype from a `.h` file. Are there more files involved or is the problem reproducible with just the given example?

Comment: The problem was reproduceable with the given information. I have tested enough to come to the conclusion that this is the fault of the Web-CAT grading software, and not Doxygen, so I will be closing this